# Keep original string language in laravel slug

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, slug, laravel-helper

With laravel(I am using v.9.x) Str:slug you can convert a string to a slug like:

```
Woman life freedom
```

to

```
Woman-life-freedom
```

but the problem is when you pass a non-english string to this method, laravel translates it to English like in persian:

```
زن زندگی آزادی
```

it converts to:

```
zn-zndgy-azady
```

How to prevent laravel to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to this problem is to pass `null` or `0` as the third argument to the method `slug` like this:

```
Str:slug('String', '-', null);
```

##### Why?

if you look at the source code of the slug method in the `Str` class at `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php`, you can see this:

```
public static function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = 'en', $dictionary = ['@' => 'at'])
{
    $title = $language ? static::ascii($title, $language) : $title;
```

It is clear that the third parameter `$language` allows you to translate the language if it is specified, else it will use English as the default.

So by passing the value `0` (or `null`, that is better), the condition is not executed and the text remains in its original form.

Comment: the `$language` is `string|null` so `null` would be more accurate even though it is just doing a truthy check

Comment: @lagbox yeah you are right that is more accurate

Comment: worked fine for me for thai language